# Disable Smartphone OnScreen Keyboard on Form

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, calendar

I want to add a calendar-picker in my homepage (like http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck2.shtml). But everytime I click on the form with the calendar, ios and android-phones open the on-screen-keyboard.

Is there a way (html, php, js?) to disable the on-screen-keyboard on this specific form?

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable on screen keyboard for all mobile devices

**Solution**

Don't use textbox for your date picker .. use a `<div id="fakeTextBox"> </div>` styled like a textbox using css ...

Thank would do the trick on all mobile device

Thanks

:)